# Please tell me sentences' meaning difference

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could anyone please tell me sentences' meaning difference? as once place it is used **needed** and another place it is used **need**

10,000 U.S.-supported civilians **needed** to fight Ebola

And

10,000 U.S.-supported civilians **need** to fight Ebola

Thanks,
Alish

Comment: "10,000 U.S.-supported civilians needed to fight Ebola" as written is probably not a sentence by itself. More context would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first use, "needed", means "In order to fight Ebola, 10,000 people are required in order for the effort to be successful", while the second can have various meanings. Generally, it suggests that 10,000 people are at risk from the spread of Ebola, either directly or indirectly, and if these people don't fight Ebola they will be harmed by their inaction (they need to fight Ebola). It can also mean that 10,000 people have a moral obligation to fight Ebola, but that is unlikely in this context.

ETA - The second meaning of "need" can be illustrated with "Your house is on fire. You need to get out now."

Comment: Thank you for explaining, Regarding 1) sentence if i want to use "need" in past tense then what would be the sentence as "ed" is already used here.

Comment: 10,000 U.S.-supported civilians were needed to fight Ebola